# Is my CPU running hot?

Tags: temperature, intel-core-i5

I have a core i5 2500k which I believe is running a bit hot at idle speed. It idles at about 35° Celsius on the stock cooler. 
Everyone says that the computers idle temps are individual to everybody elses due to climate, case etc.
My computer consists of:

- Core i5 2500k Stock Cooler No OC
- Asus Radeon 6950 Direct CuII
- Antec 1200 Full Tower Case
- Mushkin Blackline 8GB 2x4GB 1600mhz
- Asus P8Z68-V PRO
- 1TB Seagate 7200rpm

Something that I find interesting is that the temperatures are different according to the program I am using. I just don't know what to trust. For example, Speccy always says my MOBO temp is 60° and never changes. I know it has to be wrong.

Current temps according to programs are:
Speccy - 34°
Asus AI Suite -24°
Coretemp - 35°

I am starting to think that this might be a software program than a hardware problem. I can't tell which program is true.

Answer (score 3):

No, I would not worry until it hits 70+.

Temperatures in the 30's are nothing at all to worry about (your laptop will probably not feel warm at that temp).

Comment: I've got a home server box, and it's not even set to spin up the fan really until it gets to 60C.

Comment: Just to clarify, it is a Desktop PC. Unless of course you are comparing the temps to that of a laptop. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Does not matter if its a desktop or a laptop.